# Android APK Size is mostly the Design Support libraries

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk, android-support-library

So I've made a relatively simple app, a couple of pages and basic text in/out functions. I'm using Xamarin. My compiled code is a couple of hundered KB, but the app's total size, for say the ARM ABI, is 21.7MB, and when I break the APK open, it's the android support libraries that seem to be taking 50% of the size up. Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the root view:
[image]

And here's the assemblies folder:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `Linker` in Android release mode is set to `Link SDK Only`. You can strip *more* **unused** `IL` code from the assemblies by setting it to `Link All Assemblies`, but beware, the linker works on static code references, so any code usage ref'd by reflection would not be seen and removed.

You need to make sure you are throughly testing your release builds for faults related to this and use the various linker preservation techniques (Ref: [Linking on Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/))

`Xamarin.Android` Hello World app using `Android.Support.V7` and  `Android.Support.V4`

#### Link SDK Only

```
13M ./assemblies

├── [    2988032]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll
├── [    2398208]  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll
└── [    1985024]  mscorlib.dll
├── [    1357312]  Mono.Android.dll
├── [     915456]  System.Xml.dll
├── [     809984]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll
├── [     737280]  System.dll
├── [     710656]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll
├── [     426496]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll
├── [     265216]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll
├── [     114176]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll
├── [      93184]  Java.Interop.dll
├── [      75776]  AppV4V7Size.dll
├── [      49664]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll
├── [      37888]  Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll
├── [      37888]  System.Core.dll
├── [      11264]  System.Runtime.dll
├── [       5632]  System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
├── [       5632]  System.Reflection.dll
├── [       5120]  System.Threading.dll
├── [       5120]  System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Collections.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
├── [       4096]  System.Linq.dll
```

#### Link All Assemblies (9MB savings...)

```
3.9M    ./assemblies

└── [    1880576]  mscorlib.dll
├── [     785408]  Mono.Android.dll
├── [     392192]  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll
├── [     222720]  System.dll
├── [     187392]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll
├── [     120320]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll
├── [     115712]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll
├── [      92160]  Java.Interop.dll
├── [      75776]  AppV4V7Size.dll
├── [      52736]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll
├── [      39936]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll
├── [      37376]  System.Core.dll
├── [      11264]  System.Runtime.dll
├── [       7680]  Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll
├── [       5632]  System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
├── [       5632]  System.Reflection.dll
├── [       5120]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll
├── [       5120]  System.Threading.dll
├── [       5120]  System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
├── [       4608]  Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Collections.dll
├── [       4608]  System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
├── [       4096]  System.Linq.dll
```

Comment: Okay, so I tested this, and yes the app is smaller, but it also no longer works presumably because of what you said about referenced by reflection - the problem is, I have no idea why you mean by that. The app crashes on the splash screen immediately, here's the code for it: http://pastebin.com/raw/R9f5H5Pu - am I referencing something by reflection? If so, cna you tell me what?

Comment: In DDMS it say's it's failing to inflate the axml, caused by: java.lang.classnotfoundexception: android.support.v7.widget.fitwindowslinearlayout - so is this now being excluded when compiled>

Comment: @JoeBrailsford No error posted... but without going through the error and/or your code, there is no way that I could tell you. Follow the link in my answer on how to preserve code and exclude assemblies from the linker. Start by excluding your code/classes (SQLite, etc... ) and progress to the framework libraries...